# Send raw file data from JavaScript to ASP.NET WebApi

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, google-drive-api

I am fetching a file from Google Drive using Picker API. I have successfully got file data from downloadUrl:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', file.downloadUrl);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
xhr.onload = function () {
     fileRecievedCallback(xhr.responseText, doc.name);
};
```

I have file data in `xhr.responseText`, Now I want to send this byte string to .Net Web api and convert that to file and save to disc. I can send this file data to web api. Question is how do I read this byte string in C# and convert it to file and save to disk?

Comment: Have you tried using: `File.WriteAllBytes(string path, byte[] bytes)` it uses `System.IO`

Comment: @JanR I have tried both `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(file));` and `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, Convert.FromBase64String(file));`. `FromBase64String` throws error that it's not Base64 string. `GetBytes` writes to file but the pdf I am writing doesn't open, it gets corrupted. Any  other thing to try?